How can I disable the Ubuntu 24.04 gestures
I installed the 24.04 version this monday and I'm getting crazy because everytime I slide my mouse on the top of the screen it goes crazy. My apps start shrinking as if I was double clicking them and it only stops when I close everything. Please help because I don't want to change back to an older version.
Edit: Maybe I need to clarify. The issue happens mainly when I click the upper bar. Then it gets crazy with the gestures.

I think this is an issue that is being tracked at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/2066169

I do not get this behavior on Ubuntu 24.04  ...  however I always disable all tiling

Run
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling false

You can also take a look at other useful options by installing dconf-editor.

It was already set to false :(

is the issue caused by you double-clicking the top bar?

The issue is that even though this setting is set to false, it's completely ignored by ubuntu and the active edges are still active. The toggle in the settings (under "multitasking") is also ignored.
